# What does TypeScript pipe operator mean when used with strings?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.1, union-types

I know about union types, but what does this pipe syntax mean?

```
let propName: "name" | "age" | "location";
```

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/12/07/announcing-typescript-2-1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer my own question: those are "String Literal Types" as in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types

> String literal types allow you to specify the exact value a string must have. In practice string literal types combine nicely with union types, type guards, and type aliases. You can use these features together to get enum-like behavior with strings.

Comment: There's a [better link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html). I like to think of it as a string-based enum. Also, it's worth noting that the `keyof` operator takes a type `T` and returns a string literal type, comprised of `T`'s properties (the expression `keyof T` is called an [**indexed type query**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types)).

Answer (score -7):

We call it pipeline operator.
The experimental pipeline operator `|>` (currently at stage 1) allows the creation of chained function calls in a readable manner. Basically, the pipeline operator provides syntactic sugar on a function call with a single argument allowing you to write

`'%21' |> decodeURI` instead of `decodeURI('%21')`.

Eg: This is how it works
[image]